# c# regex replace

Tags: c#, regex

I am creating a tool that will allow me to shift numbers by values. it has the following:

1 textbox to hold all values
3 textboxes for the entries of the modified values (X,Y,Z)
1 button to initiate the process.

when I click on the button, it first finds the regex matches:

```
string regex = @"((E6POS [\w]*={)X\s([\d.-]*)\s*,*Y\s*([-.\d]*)\s*,Z\s*([-\d.]*))";
Regex r = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

then I get the matches:

```
Match m = r.Match(txt.Text);
// once this is finished I parse through the matches and take the values and parse them. 

while (m.Success)
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    try
    {
        xf = Convert.ToDecimal(m.Groups[3].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(shiftX.Text);
        yf = Convert.ToDecimal(m.Groups[4].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(shiftY.Text);
        zf = Convert.ToDecimal(m.Groups[5].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(shiftZ.Text);

        txt.ReplaceAll(m.Groups[0].ToString(), string.Format("{0} X {1},Y {2}, Z {3}", m.Groups[2].ToString(), xf.ToString(), yf.ToString(), zf.ToString()));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        m = m.NextMatch();
    }
}
this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```

is there a faster way that i can do this? it is taking up to 30 seconds to perform this task.

Sample input text would be

DECL E6POS XJV_MOVE_3={X 3887.44,Y 0.00,Z 2594.00, A 0.00, B 90.00, C 180.00,S 22,T 18,E1 2654.30,E2 0.0,E3 0.0,E4 0.0,E5 0.0,E6 0.0 }
DECL E6POS XAX749_55_2654_3155075={X 4016.8440,Y -774.9973,Z 1437.1283, A 90.0000, B -45.0000, C -90.0000,S 22,T 26,E1 2654.3000,E2 0.0,E3 0.0,E4 0.0,E5 0.0,E6 0.0 }
DECL E6POS XAX755_55_2654_3155075={X 4016.8440,Y -810.9183,Z 1473.0493, A 90.0000, B -45.0000, C -90.0000,S 22,T 26,E1 2654.3000,E2 0.0,E3 0.0,E4 0.0,E5 0.0,E6 0.0 }
DECL FDAT FAX755_55_2654_3155075={TOOL_NO 1, BASE_NO 0, IPO_FRAME #BASE, POINT2[] "  "}
DECL LDAT LAX755_55_2654_3155075={ VEL 2.0,ACC 88.0, APO_DIST 100.0, APO_FAC 50.0, ORI_TYP #VAR}
;FOLD From Line 1411

Comment: Please provide sample input and output.

Comment: First step to make it faster is to profile it. Otherwise what do you think we should make faster?

Comment: Your while loop could be replaced with a foreach(MatchM in r.Matches(txt.Text) - but I suspect the regex itself and the value parsed is the big issue.

Comment: Also, if there'll always be a known (i.e. 3) textboxes, you could employ different threads to do each stream of work.

Comment: would threading work because im actually looking to rewrite it all one line at a time which i wouldnt think would take so long. the problem is that the operation is performed 718 times in this file.

Comment: What is ReplaceAll? It's not a method on any textbox control I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I guess those three textboxes hold the values for shiftX, shiftY and shiftZ. In that case move the "Convert.ToDecimal" of those fixed values (fixed as in: does not change within the loop) ouside the loop. That will save some processing.

Also: try holding the new value in a temporary variable, instead of in that result textbox. That may save some time rendering a value that will be changed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is elsewhere. How do you measure?

Since I don't know what your `ReplaceAll` is, I changed it to string.Replace. Then I ran your code. It took **1ms**. Below is what I ran. You can compile and run this code yourself and measure how long it executes on your machine.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SO6329015
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string input = @"DECL E6POS XJV_MOVE_3={X 3887.44,Y 0.00,Z 2594.00, A 0.00, B 90.00, C 180.00,S 22,T 18,E1 2654.30,E2 0.0,E3 0.0,E4 0.0,E5 0.0,E6 0.0 } DECL E6POS XAX749_55_2654_3155075={X 4016.8440,Y -774.9973,Z 1437.1283, A 90.0000, B -45.0000, C -90.0000,S 22,T 26,E1 2654.3000,E2 0.0,E3 0.0,E4 0.0,E5 0.0,E6 0.0 } DECL E6POS XAX755_55_2654_3155075={X 4016.8440,Y -810.9183,Z 1473.0493, A 90.0000, B -45.0000, C -90.0000,S 22,T 26,E1 2654.3000,E2 0.0,E3 0.0,E4 0.0,E5 0.0,E6 0.0 } DECL FDAT FAX755_55_2654_3155075={TOOL_NO 1, BASE_NO 0, IPO_FRAME #BASE, POINT2[] "" ""} DECL LDAT LAX755_55_2654_3155075={ VEL 2.0,ACC 88.0, APO_DIST 100.0, APO_FAC 50.0, ORI_TYP #VAR} ;FOLD From Line 1411";
            const string regex = @"((E6POS [\w]*={)X\s([\d.-]*)\s*,*Y\s*([-.\d]*)\s*,Z\s*([-\d.]*))";

            const string shiftX = "7777";
            const string shiftY = "8888";
            const string shiftZ = "9999";

            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            Regex r = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            Match m = r.Match(input);

            while (m.Success)
            {
                try
                {
                    var xf = Convert.ToDecimal(m.Groups[3].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(shiftX);
                    var yf = Convert.ToDecimal(m.Groups[4].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(shiftY);
                    var zf = Convert.ToDecimal(m.Groups[5].ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(shiftZ);

                    input = input.Replace(m.Groups[0].ToString(), string.Format("{0} X {1},Y {2}, Z {3}", m.Groups[2], xf, yf, zf));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    m = m.NextMatch();
                }
            }

            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine(input);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the input text is much larger than just what i submitted. its over 1700 lines in length